# How to find all records through a has_one through relations via an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to find all payments that belong to an array of clients. The payments have a has_one, through bills relationship with clients.

The models include:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
  has_one :client, through: :bill

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bills
  has_many :payments, through: :bills

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :payments
```

I am trying to find with the following query

```
@payments = Payment.joins(:bills).where('bill.client_id IN (?)', [1,2,3,4])
```

but get a PG timeout message

tried a .includes instead of the .joins and also received a PG timeout message

and also tried

```
Payment.includes(:bill).where( bills: { 'client_id IN (?)', [1,2,3,4] } )
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How big is your database? do you have an index on bill_id? ie is it just choking on how much data you have?

Comment: Also - you have a client association on payment... have you tried something like  `Payment.joins(:client).where("clients.id" => [1,2,3,4])`

Comment: In dev, not too many records, but do have an index on client_id on the bills table, I tried the joins on client, but it also timed out

Comment: you'll want an index on bill_id too - because you are joining on that... and that will slow things down (a bit). Probably not your actual problem here, given your small dev db - but generally it's good practise to always have an index on join-columns (because when you hit prod, it will be slow)

Comment: I tried your answer again after restarting the server and it worked, took 1.9ms, tried going through the bills and it took 1.5ms, not sure which is more efficient but do like the idea of going through the clients in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your `bill` singular/plurals the wrong way around. When you make a string it has to be the table name, so it will be plural.  When you use the hash format you use the same case as your association (singular when used from `Payment`). So:

```
Payment.joins(:bill).where( bills: { client_id: [1,2,3,4] } )
```

Comment: was able to get this to work but needed bills not bill in the `Payment.joins(:bill).where( bills: { client_id: [1,2,3,4] } )`

Comment: Seems that joins is faster than includes, does anyone know if joins is preferred?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll edit my answer (I could have sworn it was the name of the association, thanks).

Comment: Re your other question, `joins` and `includes` do different things, `joins` does an `INNER JOIN` and `includes` either does a second (single) `SELECT` with all the IDs from the first resultset, or it does an `OUTER JOIN`.